# How do i update my html only when a change happens to a file stored on a server?

Tags: javascript, php

So i have been making a chatroom on a website using php and javascript. I have been using the function setInterval to update the chat every few seconds but that has been causing me problems. Is there any way to update the chat only when a new message has been recieved by the server?

Comment: chatroom needs the realtime, so why not using server like firebase instead of using setInterval?

Comment: Websockets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the chat periodically, make an ajax call to you server every X seconds and IF there are new chat messages, THEN grab them from the server and reload the page.